# In nltk tree how can I access a parent from a child?

Tags: python, nltk

Suppose I had a variable that holds a tree of nltk tree class. Is there any function like parent() or something that returns the parent of the node?

Answer (score 6):

You need a different data structure: A tree whose nodes contain pointers to their parent. The NLTK now provides the type `nltk.tree.ParentedTree` (as @Gerhard already pointed out). But the NLTK corpora and tools generate plain `Tree` objects, so you need to convert. If you have a variable `mytree` that contains your tree, convert it like this:

```
from nltk.tree import ParentedTree
newtree = ParentedTree.convert(mytree)
```

The nodes of the new tree will have a `parent()` method that you can use to navigate up the tree.

Answer (score 5):

With NLTK 3, you can use [`nltk.tree.ParentedTree`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.ParentedTree) 
It has a `parent()` method.